# Logic error or syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to perform a query in result page that select the information that bigger than a form data pass from index page.

The value passed from index page is correct which as seen as below:

```
Array
(
[device] => sim only
[provider1] => umobile
[plantype] => postpaid
[dusage] => 3
[cusage] => 0
[musage] => 300
)
```

but my result show is not as expected. I wonder is my logic error or my syntax error?

Here is my query code:

```
 <?php
                //$planquery="SELECT * FROM plan";
                $dquery= "SELECT * FROM details";
                $device = $_POST['device'];
                $provider1 = $_POST['provider1'];
                //$provider2 = $_POST['provider2'];
                //$provider3 = $_POST['provider3'];
                //$provider4 = $_POST['provider4'];
                $plantype = $_POST['plantype'];
                $dusage = $_POST['dusage'];
                $cusage = $_POST['cusage'];
                $musage = $_POST['musage'];
                $planquery="SELECT * FROM plan WHERE 
                            Phone='$device' AND SIMTYPE='$plantype' AND 'DATA'>='$dusage' AND 'CALL'>='$cusage' AND 'MSG'>='$musage' "; 
                $planresult=mysql_query($planquery) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
                $dresult=mysql_query($dquery) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
                //$sresult=mysql_query($squery) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
                while ((($prow = mysql_fetch_assoc($planresult))) && ($drow = mysql_fetch_assoc($dresult)) ) {

                ?>
```

I have two details which is

1. 500 free msg
2. 200 free msg

Form data is contain user search require, in case user search for 500msg. The query I want to do is only select the record that when 'MSG'>='$musage' also other requirement. The both result shown as result; this is what is not as expected.

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: @Glide mean i have to change my code to PDO_MySQL extension ??

Comment: yes But this not the solution on your problem this only to prevent SQL injections

Comment: What do you mean by "not as expected"

Comment: You fetch two queries in the same loop, are you sure about that?

Comment: @olibiaz

i have two details which is
1. 500 free msg
2. 200 free msg

form data is contain user search require, in case user search for 500msg.


The query i want to do is only select the record that when 'MSG'>='$musage' also other requirement.

the both result shown as result.<<<this is what "not as expected"

Comment: @olibiaz sure cause i have two table, that need to shown from query

Comment: Yes but fetching them in the same loop can cause problems, if you have more result in one than in the other, you will not fetch all the data. What do you do in this loop. You should not fetch both queries in the same loop

Comment: @olibiaz i have two table one contain plan details, one contains plan sub details, in result show i need both content to be show, show i need fetch both table in same loop.

will be the possible that my data type is not availble for compare with ">"??

Comment: Please show us the structure of your tables. Can you link the tables together? Is there any id that you can use join on?

Comment: I have repaired the `solved` and added an answer, and downvoted as this has already been asked of you. In relation to your code, you have a serious SQL injection vulnerability,  and your system may get hacked if it goes live like that. Please fix!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved this question by restructure the table, so that it is more easy to do query. Left Join used by me, rather than pull from both table.